# Question about an inequality which seems right but not easy to prove

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

The origin problem is as follows:

let $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers,and $a+b+c+d=4$
prove:$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a}\geq 4+\frac{1}{4}[(a−b)^2+(b−c)^2+(c−d)^2+(d−a)^2]$$

The solution is easy enough, which is to plug $4 = a+b+c+d $ into to $RHS$ and then move it to $LHS$, notice:
$$[\frac{(a-b)^2}{b}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{c}+\frac{(c-d)^2}{d}+\frac{(d-a)^2}{a}](a+b+c+d) \geq [(a−b)^2+(b−c)^2+(c−d)^2+(d−a)^2]$$

which would finally lead to the proof of the problem.

However, when I tried to solve the problem, I applied the Lagrange identical equation to the $RHS$ of the inequality, then I left out some quadratic term which finally leads to the inequality:
$$\color{Blue}{\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a}\geq a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$$

Which seems quite right, but I'm not really sure if it is. However, numerical tests imply that it is right. But I'm still not sure.

That stuff is kind of like Chebyshev inequality but it can't be directly used here.

From another point of view, my question is whether the following strengthening　of the origin inequality is right or not:

let $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers,and $a+b+c+d=4$
then:$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a}\geq 4+\frac{1}{4}[(a−b)^2+(b−c)^2+(c−d)^2+(d−a)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2]$$

Comment: In your second displayed formula the factor (a+b+c+d) should be erased.

Comment: I just saw the similar inequality in a book, which holds for 3 positive numbers a,b and c. However, the book doesn't give an answer to that.

Comment: @Macavity Would you please kindly give me an example where that doesn't hold?

Comment: @Macavity Sorry to reply late. There are 3 inequalities in my question. The first is proved. I can't prove the second but my guess is that holds for the same $a,b,c,d$, which is equivalent to the 3rd inequality under this circumstance. Suppose a is biggest among $a,,b,c,d$, I did some numerical work and the 2nd inequality always holds. What's more, I saw a similar inequality in a book, but there are just 3 variables and no answer is given there. Thus I hold the view that the last 2 inequalities for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Sorry, but I mean the last 2 are the same, and the 1st is proved, would you please give me some advice how to improve my question.

Comment: Ah  didn't notice that.

Comment: By Michael Rozenberg , since not $\frac14$ ,but 1 is ok.Even if add two members ,no problem.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Do you mean the coefficient? But I can't see why 1 is okay by the same method, at least not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}-4=\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b}-2a+b\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{b}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}|a-b|\right)^2}{4}\geq\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2$

Comment: Thank you but I think this is the answer to the original problem, which I've already post.

Comment: Still, your last step is not right.

Comment: @cxz why my last step is not right?

Comment: take a look again, it's obvious,isn't it?

Comment: @cxz Let $|a-b|=x$, $|b-c|=y$, $|c-d|=z$ and $|d-a|=t$. Hence, $(x+y+z+t)^2\geq x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$. Am I wrong?

Comment: oh sorry,i made a mistake, it's correct